# Should developers from different projects do a stand-up meeting together in Scrum?

Tags: scrum, agile, daily-scrum

I am from small organization, where currently we are planning to practice stand-up meetings. There are three developers currently, one developer is involved in two projects and the other two are each in one.

I'm confused as to whether all these three should do the stand-up meeting together or separately, project wise. What impact can it make if it is held all together?

Answer (score 2):

The idea of a daily stand-up meeting is to help developers synchronise their activities.

So the answer to your question is that developers should engage in a stand-up meeting together if they have a *daily* need to synchronise their activities.

For example:

Project A: Jane and Bob

Project B: Sam and Bob

Bob needs to synchronise with Jane as they work together on Project A. Bob also needs to synchronise with Sam as they work together on Project B. But Jane does not need to synchronise with Sam as they are not working on the same project.

In this situation we would have two stand-up meetings. One for Project A and one for Project B.

Comment: Kind of late to the game here, but here it goes. Is there any scrum course or something like that which you can reference?

Comment: Rather than reference a course, I would instead recommend some excellent trainers. Mike Cohn and Martine Devos are both great Scrum trainers.

Comment: Trainers, courses, doesn't matter. I'd just like a to have some concrete references to show to my seemingly misguided scrum masters. Easier to argue with them when I can quote an authority figure or paper or something.

Comment: I have found that there isn't much in the way concrete references in the agile world. Often the best source of authoritive information is the blog posts of people like Ken Schwaber, Mike Cohn, Martin Fowler, etc. And of course the Scrum Guide is always an excellent reference.

Answer (score 0):

As you described, you are planning to practice stand up meetings.
So my first questions are: What do you expect from a daily? Why do you plan to have one?

In such a small company I would have all people in a stand up --> CEO, Sales, Project Manager, Developers. Talk to each other, offer and demand help if you need some.
But this has nothing to do with scrum. It's just for information exchange.

Comment: All developer can have clarity about their daily work. I'm planing to make all team member ready for agile. In couple of next month its possible we can have more member in company.

Comment: I'd avoid this, as it could transform a daily scrum into a reporting meeting.

Comment: Avoiding it means, that you don't face the challenge to create an environment where open exchange is welcome. 

If you follow the scrum guide, a development team of at least three members (per project) is highly recommended. So for me the "teams" are too small to do Scrum. So if you don't do Scrum, there is no need to "shut oneself off".

Answer (score 0):

As Barnaby mentioned (+1!) you should be using daily scrum when there are tasks to align.

However, in such a small team with (it seems) low relationship between them, each one would be taking about topics that would add low to no value for each other.

On the other hand, if you want to have a multi skilled team capable of covering all projects, you could benefit of having developers rotating across projects. This way, each one would know where the project is by the time they have to move into it.

Bottomline: don't do daily scrum unless the team feels the need of it. Daily scrum is a tool for a mean, not the result itself.